# Setting CommandArgument for a Gridview

Tags: asp.net

I want to set a CommandArgument for a Gridview but if I run the programm an error occured.

Here is my ButtonField declaration:

```
<asp:ButtonField Text="Löschen" CommandName="Deleterecord"  ButtonType="Button" CommandArgument=<% Eval("userId") %>  />
```

and this is the error:

```
Parser Error Message: Literal content ('<asp:ButtonField Text="Löschen" CommandName="Deleterecord"  ButtonType="Button" CommandArgument=') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection'.
```

**EDIT:**

with these block of code I fill my Gridview:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Guid g = Guid.Parse("ef7a9f97-6a9a-44c6-ac38-82a5d06c394e");
            RoutesManager rm = new RoutesManager(g);
            rm.GetAllRoutes();
            List<Route> result;
            result=rm.GetAllRoutes();

            GridView1.DataSource = result;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
```

and this is GetallRoutes:

```
 public List<Route> GetAllRoutes()
        {
            var inputParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            var xmlHelper = new XmlHelper();
            var result = new List<Route>();

            inputParams.Add("UserId", _userId);

            DataTable dt = _dbhelper.Select("SELECT * FROM ROUTES WHERE UserId=@UserId", inputParams);

            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(row[XmldocPosition].ToString());               
                result.Add(xmlHelper.ConvertXmlDocumentToRoute(xmlDoc.ToXDocument()));
            }

             return result;
```

}

My grid view full with this block of code ,I put a link button in my Gridview for each Row and I want if the user click this button only this row is deleted from DB and Gridview

Comment: Do you know your eval statement is missing a closing bracket?

Comment: I assumed so! Is userid a field in your result set? Does CommandArgument="<%# UserId %>" work?

Comment: The user can't see this field in a gridview.This field is a primary key of the Table and I want to get this value and then delete this row from Gridview

Comment: Can you post the code where you databind the GridView so we can see what the actual data looks like? Sometimes, CommandArgument="<%# Container.UserId %>" is what you need, where Container is the item you are databinding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing

- A closing bracket
- Double quotes on the `userID`
- Single quote to contain the resulting value of CommandArgument

  `<asp:ButtonField Text="Löschen" CommandName="Deleterecord"  ButtonType="Button" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("userId") %>'  />`

Comment: I prefer all of things,which you saud.but the problem remains :(

Comment: I think an # is still missing from above statement it must be 
<% #Eval("userId") %>

Answer (score 0):

```
CommandArgument="<% Eval(userId) %>"
```

Try checking the formatting of your statement.  Notice the ""'s and the closing ).