# Repeater does not fire ItemCommand

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, repeater, itemcommand

I Have read similar questions and answers to my question, and I have done the recommendations but still my problem is unsolved PLZ don't mark my question as repetitive.

I have a repeater which contains a  tag. I want when user click this link , itemcommend of repeater fire. I have set itemcommand for repeater but it does not fire. My page viewstate is true and my repeater just bind one time.
this is my asp code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Rep" runat="server" onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand"  EnableViewState="true">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a  id="linkq" commandname="link" runat="server" href='<%# Eval("url") %>'  > <%# Eval("title") %> </a> 
        <%# Eval("url")%> </span>
        <%# Eval("description")%> </span>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This is my c# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // I Bind  Repeater here
    }
}

protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "link")
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check for case-sensivity. It is calld `OnItemCommand` and `CommandName`.

Comment: Case does not matter here, it works with `onitemcommand` and `commandname`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation, I normally use a `LinkButton` instead of the `<a>` tag.

`<asp:LinkButton  ID="linkq" CommandName="link" runat="server"> <%# Eval("title") %> </asp:LinkButton>`

Comment: TNX . but I did it before  and nothing changed

Comment: Did you have the `href` attribute in there when you first tried it?  That may have thrown things off too.

Comment: @Mary, What are you expecting to happen? Because bpechkis answer works.

Comment: @bpechkis yes i had href

Comment: If all you want to do is to redirect to a URL, then I would go back to your original `<a>` tag and remove the OnItemCommand from the repeater and remove the CommandName from the a tag.  There is no reason to hit the code-behind again unless you need to do some other, more complicated logic

Comment: @bpechkis I want when user click on the link , I save the url which is clicked and choosed among other urls, because I show a list of urls to user by repeater

Comment: Because it will redirect to the URL before it has a change to postback to the server.  The PostBackUrl superceeds the ItemCommand.  If you need to do something in the ItemCommand before redirecting, then keep it as I suggested and do a Response.Redirect inside the if in the ItemCommand method.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then, I would set the CommandArgument property of the LinkButton to the url they click, rather than the PostbackUrl.  (See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073728/setting-commandargument-for-a-gridview) for an example; they show it with a Button, but it should still work with a LinkButton.)  That way, in the `Repeater1_ItemCommand` method, you can do `e.CommandArgument` to retrieve the URL they clicked.

Comment: @bpechkis your suggestion worked correctly tnx a lot for the time you spent for my question